# How to remove Field from FieldArray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to remove field from filed array using redux-from,

```
<button
   type="button"
   class="btn btn-danger"
   onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
   >Remove
</button>
```

it's successfully removing filed from filed array state ( `action @@redux-form/ARRAY_REMOVE` ) but i want to remove it from my server, so how to dispatch this action to my reducer

i tried following [post](https://mycodesmells.com/post/advanced-field-arrays-with-redux-form) but not worked for me

Comment: can you share the giturl of your project code?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/adyjoe

Comment: where is this code import { Actions } from '../../../_actions';  ?

Comment: if you could, you can share the your project setup..